# What is difference between Type Annotations and Type Inference?

Tags: typescript

I was going through a TypeScript Tutorial and encountered with these terms: Type Annotations and Type Inference. I am not satisfied with the web explanation and not getting clear difference out of it. Need simple difference based explanation.

Comment: Did you read this article.
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-inference

Comment: No, I mean clear difference between both terms with example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference is where the compiler works out the type on your behalf:

```
const a = 'Some value';
```

The variable `a` has an *inferred* type of `string`.

A type annotation is where you explicitly state the type:

```
const a: string = 'Some value';
```

You have specifically indicated that this should be a string with a type annotation (typically in the format `: type`).

The practical difference is that where types can be inferred, you save a great deal of typing without losing the benefits. In some cases, being explicit can be beneficial:

- When creating an object with a literal value - as it catches mis-typed members
- Function signatures - as parameter types are tricky to infer and return types will end up as a union of types found in return statements, so you might not realise you are returning different types in different cases

Comment: Thanks!! This Explains!!